# Inner class in Tapestry pages

Tags: tapestry

Can we declare/create inner class in Tapestry page and access it to the corresponding .tml page? If yes, then how? If not, could anyone explain why?

Need your valuable input guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this works. The inner class is live reloaded but is not instrumented as a component class.

I've started using this technique to define data objects needed by the page, since I can update the @Validate annotations, or even change the available properties, on the fly.

Comment: M Lewis - the point " since I can update the @Validate annotations, or even change the available properties, on the fly." is not clear. could you please put some more light on that point if my doubt is genuine?

Comment: Tapestry users annotations on a data object to automatically provide client-side and server-side validations.  However, most data objects are not live-reloaded. By making the data object an inner class of a page, it is live-reloaded. Now I can add or change @Validate annotations on fields and refresh the browser to see the validations in effect.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and am sharing it with you.

Let's assume we have a tapestry page named Tpage.

```java
public class Tpage {  
    // variables  
    @Property  
    private TpageInnerClass innerclass;  

    //some methods  

    // Inner class  
    public class TpageInnerClass { 
        // variable  
        //methods  
    }
}
```

Now you can access the inner class variable in `Tpage.tml`.

Hope it is clear to all of you. Though I am still looking for experts comments.

Comment: so essentially there's no difference to a normal class .. and just like any page property you need to either make a public getter, or annotate as @Property. nothing to see here.